# Google console indexing request rejected due to FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, robots.txt

First, let me say that Shopify couldn't figure this out, nor people I tried to hire on Fiverr.

My site seemingly, and for no apparent reason, got messed up on Google.
My traffic went down to 0 and the culprit is Indexing.

1. Google console suddenly says that my main domain's URL is not on Google.
2. On Bing, I am able to get indexed with no issue
3. In Mobile-Friendly Test it says that "Page cannot be reached" (however I am able to see the site on mobile)
4. On Google's pagespeed test, it gives a lighthouse error. (screenshot attached)
5. When trying to request indexing, I get an error "Indexing request rejected"
6. When re-submitting the sitemap (that was always fine in the past) it can't be fetched. (There is no problem with the sitemap and it exists on the site) Console says "sitemap could not be read - General HTTP error"
7. Console says that site might be blocked by robots.txt but I checked and the site is NOT being blocked there (and the file exists on the site)
8. I have no removal requests for pages on my site.
9. I am a verified owner of the site.
10. I did not remove the HTTP property.
11. When trying to test robots.txt, I get the error "robots.txt fetch failed

p.s. I used the new "DOMAIN" section when adding a property, which includes both HTTP and https (i.imgur.com/oCgAvZa.png). Anyway, I also added https and by default, Shopify will direct HTTP to https and that's why in console, you see by https is says "redirected." I have the exact same issue in the HTTP property.

Attached are some screenshots.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It appears you have CloudFlare enabled on this site. Have you tried testing it without Cloudflare by [pausing](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/how-do-i-temporarily-disable-cloudflare/68798/2) it and entering [Development Mode](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168246-Understanding-Cloudflare-Development-Mode) to bypass caching? Is the last screenshot of your site's code (it would be helpful if you labeled them)? Obviously the [noindex](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag) `instructs Google specifically not to show this page in its search results`

Comment: Your site isn't working when tried on my browser. Is the server up?

Comment: @dan Shopify uses Cloudflare and I can't disable it. I removed the code screenshot. That noindex is my custom one that I use for a few pages that I don't want indexed (for example:  {% if handle contains 'thank-you-20' %}     <meta name="robots" content="noindex">{% endif %} This code has always been there and didn't cause an issue.

Comment: @Kannan What is the url that you are typing? did you try crayolex (.com)? I have no problem accessing the site on PC and mobile and I used VPNs to test as well. What Country are you from?

Comment: @ZviTwersky Yes, I tried the exact URL you have mentioned but from outside the United States. May be a firewall block. Just checked on webpagetest.org and the site works fine from US.

Comment: @Kannan That's strange. I am able to surf my site using a VPN from India. I don't think that's the issue. https://i.imgur.com/ipjaVj9.png

Comment: @Kannan also checked on https://asm.ca.com/en/ping.php and it seems that my site loads in all Countries. Not sure why you can't access it. https://i.imgur.com/ofWEQ7x.png check top of screenshot - says India Bangalore 100% packets lost. That's the only place that has an issue. Maybe you're from there?

Comment: @ZviTwersky CDN's are common causes of these types of errors - if you can, try to check with it disabled. Your question's description also only mentions using an `HTTP` property, did you also create an `HTTPS` property as detailed [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592), and try using that? It seems your site is indexed, but only for `HTTPS` since there's a redirect from `HTTP` (so URLs with `http:" would no longer be indexed).

Comment: Yes, my place is close to Bangalore (its about 200 miles to the east of Bangalore). Now I had an interesting observation. I tried "dig" command on crayolex[.]com. I got two IPs as result 216.239.36.21 and 23.227.38.32. When I hard coded  216.239.36.21 at my /etc/host, the site wasn't working. But when I used the other IP, the site worked. Interesting.  May be a DNS issue or something? Experienced members can take it further.

Comment: @dan I used the new "DOMAIN" section when adding a property, which includes both HTTP and https (https://i.imgur.com/oCgAvZa.png). Anyway, I also added https and by default, Shopify will direct HTTP to https and that's why in console, you see by https is says "redirected." I will ask Shopify about CDN.

Comment: @Kannan my domain is on Godaddy and I haven't changed any DNS records for a while

Comment: @dan by the way, also the http property has all the exact same issues as my original post.

Comment: @ZviTwersky OK, you might want to clarify that in your question because it currently just states, `I did not remove the HTTP property`, and we typically get questions where users failed to add additional properties when updating to `HTTPS`. We generally don't do troubleshooting here and close questions that [only could apply to your site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but I'll leave it open in case anyone else has run across this before.  If you figure it out (like its related to Cloudflare), please add that as an answer below and accept it.

Comment: @ZviTwersky Btw, an easy way to disable Cloudflare using GoDaddy is just to change the name servers with GoDaddy to their default ones (making sure the `A` record at least matches the same IP address of your site currently with Cloudflare). DNS updates with both are pretty quick (usually in a half hour or less), so you could test that out and then switch the name servers back without too much impact if late at night. Good luck.

Comment: @dan Shopify told me that here it seems that my site is accessible in all Countries: https://dnschecker.org/#A/crayolex.com

Comment: @ZviTwersky I think you meant to direct that comment to Kannan - I didn't comment that it wasn't reachable, Kannan did.

Answer (score 2):

Solved! You were all right, just Shopify support figured out exactly the problem.

In my DNS, I had added 5 A records of G-Suite which I should not have. You shouldn't have A records pointing to two places. Also, my CNAME was crayolex.myshopify.com and it should have been shops.myshopify.com

Now the site should load for everyone else. And, the Google Console is indexing the site. I will now fix sitemap, coverage, and anything else. Before I couldn't do anything, was just getting errors.

[image]

Comment: Glad you solved the issue (I think you meant Kannan by the way). Please accept your answer when you can.

Comment: No, I meant you. You wrote, "If you figure it out (like its related to Cloudflare), please add that as an answer below and accept it." I'll accept my answer when the platform allows me; in two days.

Comment: Great, glad I was able to help then :-)

Answer (score 1):

The website is blocked on other users network because you are not using correct implementation of https.It not your firewall, its their networks.
You have https enabled but it might be an implementation issue from your dev team end.

Three types of security symbols browser shows:

[image: Secure] Secure
[image: Info or Not Secure] Info or Not Secure
[image: Not Secure or Dangerous] Not Secure or Dangerous

Your website is showing second issue. It might work or it might not on other networks.

**You need to delete your http version and redirect all the available instance of the url to https or preferred https version** and then submit it again to the Google webmasters. Before submitting it again:

Check your .htacess
Check your robots.txt
Check your sitemap urls (do not submit different version of sitemap)
Check your domain versions (http or https, www or non-www, with "/" or without "/")

As I have investigated you website is accessible with https://crayolex.com/index.html also. It means you are giving search engines to reach your website more than one path.

Also you need to check on Google webmasters where you are submitting the website:

There are two available option on Google webmasters, please check the screenshot.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: I had already [checked](https://www.geocerts.com/ssl-checker) their SSL and there's no issues with it. There's also no indication of insecure content, there's already a redirect to `HTTPS` occurring, and the OP stated above in the comments that they're using the `Domain` property type. So although these are common issues, they really don't apply here.